# Drupal Commerce Extra Login required

Tags: commerce, users

I've enabled the Commerce Extra Login module and the login form now now appears when an anonymous or a user who is not yet logged in checks out.

Is there a settings which will make login required before a user can continue through the checkout process? I don't want users continuing without logging in or creating an account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed the same thing and couldn't get Commerce Extra Login to do it.

Fortunately, there's [Commerce Checkout Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect) which does the trick:

> This module redirects anonymous users to a page where they can login or create a new account when they try to checkout. After the user logs in or registers, he is redirected to the checkout in order to finalize his order.

Answer (score 0):

To fix that just comment out the if statement:

```
if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
```

on

```
function commerce_extra_login_page_login_pane_checkout_form_validate
```